# Fetching user with cookies in Next 13 API route

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes, strapi

I have a `Navbar.LinkItems` component that uses the 'use client' directive in a `Navbar` component which is a server component. From the `Navbar.LinkItems` component, I am attempting to fetch a user data after user successfully logs in in order to show the logout button like this:

```
//Navbar.LinkItems component

'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { SVGDottedLoader } from '../loaders/loaders';
import useGetUser from '@/app/hooks/getUser';
import Link from "next/link";

export default function NavbarLinks(){
    const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(false)
    const { data, error, mutate } = useGetUser()

    const router = useRouter()

    const logout = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setShowLoader(true)
        
        const resp = await fetch(`/api/logout`)
        const data = await resp.json()


        if (data.isLoggedOut) {
            mutate(null)
            router.push('/login')
            setShowLoader(false)
        }
    }


    return <>
    <div>
        <Link href="/">Index</Link>
        <Link href="/">Why venuce</Link>
        <Link href="/">Listings</Link>
        <Link href="/login">Login</Link>
        <Link href="/">Join</Link>
        <Link href="/">Dashboard</Link>
    </div>
    <div>
    
        {
            error ? 'Error' 
            : !data ? 'Loading'
            : data.user ? <>
            
            {
                showLoader 
                ? <Loader /> : <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
            }
            
            </> : 'No user'
        }
        
    </div>
    </>
}
```

```
//In the utils/getUser.js file

'use client'

import useSWR from "swr"

const fetcher = async (url) => {
    const resp = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    const data = await resp.json()
    return data
}


export default function useGetUser() {
    const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR(`/api/user`, fetcher, { refreshInterval: 5 })

    return { data, error, mutate }
}
```

```
//In /api/user api route

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export async function GET() {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const token = cookieStore.get('jwt')


    if (token) {

        const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/users/me?populate=user_type,profile_picture`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token.value}`
            },
            cache: 'no-cache'
        })

        const user = await resp.json()

        return NextResponse.json({ token, user }, { status: 200 });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ token }, { status: 200 });

}
```

The user data is successfully returned when in development mode. However in production mode, `useSWR` doesn't find the cookies so the user is not returned. What is the best approach this problem?